# Is it possible to establish some connection between materials with physics and physical properties?

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor, physics

One thing that bothers me a bit in Blender (or maybe in other similar frameworks) is it seems that materials and physics seem to be totally independent of each other, at least in Blender. However, in reality for instance, a shiny object cannot naturally have a coarse surface, or the possibility of that happening is pretty low (maybe in Diamond?). I wonder, is it possible to somehow establish some connection from material nodes in Blender to physical properties? Has anyone done anything similar in this vein to automatically adjust the physical parameters (or somehow influence them) based on the materials or give some distribution on the physical parameters given the material properties?

Note: my guess is this is something that has not been done before. Therefore, relevant resources would also be considered as answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "physical properties" here?

Comment: @lemon Any physical properties like mass (as a function of the materials and scale of the shape say), friction, damping etc

Comment: @lemon Even knowing whether some people have done some stuff in this avenue helps me a lot. Would appreciate if you can point me to their works.

Comment: You can influence material from one specific object using drivers or addons like Animation Nodes. But I don't know a way to do it when a given material is applied to several objects with different physical properties

Comment: if you mean automatically, I guess no, not in Blender. Materials are just appearance, while physics is just object reaction to world forces (and other objects through collisions maybe). You can of course script (with drivers, as suggested above) some influence but it could easily become a really complex job... simulate the _real_ world is complicated!

Comment: @m.ardito You said *not in Blender*. Do you know any other framework that provides such thing? and to what extend?

Comment: I don't know any specific product, but I know there are (complex) software simulators, mostly in the engineering area that evaluate models physical properties based both on their design and material specification... they are used to design eg: cars, planes, engines, to evaluate how a specific product (even small parts) will behave under stress conditions, temperature, pressure, and the like...  Blender is an artist's tool, and similar tools are far beyond its scope...